# Issue with TLS between Fluent-bit client and Fluentd server

Tags: docker, fluentd, fluent-bit

I am trying to connect a fluent-bit client (running in Docker container) to a server running Fluentd with TLS.

Fluent-bit Client config:

```
[SERVICE]
    Flush   2
    Daemon  Off
    Log_level   debug

[INPUT]
    Name    Dummy

[OUTPUT]
    Name    forward
    Host    SERVER_IP
    Port    PORT
    tls     on
    tls.ca_file     /tls/certs/ca.crt.pem
    tls.crt_file    /tls/certs/client.crt.pem
    tls.key_file    /tls/private/client.key.pem
    tls.key_passwd  PASSWORD
    tls.debug  3
```

Fluentd server config:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  @id input_forward
  port PORT
  # tls
  <transport tls>
    version     TLSv1_2
    ca_path  /etc/td-agent/tls/certs/ca.crt.pem
    cert_path  /etc/td-agent/tls/certs/server.crt.pem
    private_key_path  /etc/td-agent/tls/private/server.key.pem
    private_key_passphrase PASSWORD
    ca_private_key_passphrase PASSWORD
  </transport>
</source>
```

When I start services on both ends and try to send a message, this error shows in the Fluentd (server) logs:

```
2020-11-06 11:30:45 -0500 [warn]: #0 [input_forward] unexpected error before accepting TLS connection by OpenSSL error_class=OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError error="SSL_accept returned=1 errno=0 state=error: sslv3 alert bad certificate"
```

However, when I manually try to connect the client to Fluentd server using the openssl command line tool, the connection works:

```
openssl s_client -connect IPADDR:PORT -CAfile certs/ca.crt.pem -cert certs/client.crt.pem -key private/client.key.pem -tls1_2 -state -quiet
```

Therefore, I assume that the server is enforcing some check that the openssl CL client is performing, but the fluent-bit running in Docker container is not.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

On the fluentd side, I had to add a ca_private_key_path

```
<transport tls>
    #min_version TLSv1_1
    version     TLSv1_2
    ca_path  /etc/td-agent/tls/certs/ca.crt.pem
    cert_path  /etc/td-agent/tls/certs/server.crt.pem
    # ADD CA PRIVATE KEY
    ca_private_key_path /etc/td-agent/tls/private/ca.key.pem
    private_key_path  /etc/td-agent/tls/private/server.key.pem
</transport>
```

Comment: How could this be correct?  The server shouldn't have to have the private key of the CA to authenticate client certificates _issued_ by that CA, that breaks the whole security of an issuing CA.